# Changing ownership of google drive file not working - Insufficient permissions for this file

Tags: google-api-python-client

As a google driver user (using my gmail account) I want to transfer ownership of my uploaded files to another user (using their gmail account).

I found this handy tool: https://github.com/davidstrauss/google-drive-recursive-ownership , which makes this call:

```
service.permissions().update(fileId=drive_item['id'], 
    permissionId=permission_id, body=permission, transferOwnership=True).execute()
```

I've verified the fileId is correct and the permission_id is correct, along with the permission object that is being passed in as the body.

The code seems good, and it runs great against google drive "native" files (like the google docs and spreadsheets).

But when run against an uploaded PDF, this error occurs:

```
<HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Bxz4bvKt4QekTWlUUHg0XzUydTa/permissions/18055737357773114524
    ?transferOwnership=true&alt=json returned "Insufficient permissions for this file">
```

Any ideas on why changing ownership of "native" google drive files works fine when using the 'update' method but changing ownership of uploaded files (like PDFs and docx files) doesn't?

Answer (score 7):

Changing the ownership of non-Google docs within Google drive can only be done with a Google Apps account, not a regular Google account.

So in order for your script to work, you either need to use a Google Apps account for authentication or there's a few messy workarounds below;

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/Hz1uUukwKmk
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/VPhNE_HkGLs

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @MarcinKoziński The question is *"Any ideas on why changing ownership of "native" google drive files works fine when using the 'update' method but changing ownership of uploaded files (like PDFs and docx files) doesn't?"* The links do not answer this question, my answer content does. The links are workarounds for the issue he is having which is not fixable. Please read the question before reviewing answers.

Comment: Hi Jay, this is why I only added this as a comment, I did not recommend deletion of your post. If those links are not essential then maybe just delete them? My comment still holds, those links could become useless, so if you want to recommend workarounds then it's still better to include them here and post links for reference.

Comment: @MarcinKoziński I did not say the links were not essential. I said that they are workarounds not answers. I am not including long copy and pasted workarounds in my answer because the OP did not ask for that (hence why I only gave links). He asked why something was failing. If the links become useless (which they won't) I will happily remove them.

Comment: As the bounty provider - Can I request some sort of explanation of what a google apps account is?

Comment: @DAdams An Apps account is basically another name for a business account. It's a Google account that's associated with a domain (example.com) - Pretty sure you have to pay for one, not sure if there's a free subscription. As for directionality, I have no idea I'm afraid. I would assume apps account -> regular would work but there may be permission issues as it's outside of your domain. Sorry I can't be much help!

Answer (score 3):

Check whether it is a prevent flag issue . Right click and select shares and try to see if stops you from making any further shares to other people . A file that is shared with somebody with a setting that people with whom it is shared with cannot share it , then you will get insufficient permission errors .

Comment: This is an ownership issue, not a share issue. Try giving another person ownership of a document you uploaded. (.pdf, .txt, etc... )

Comment: Ok my bad will test it n let u knw